# How do i combine echo with printf without getting the string length at the end?

Tags: php, html

```
    <?php //Php and html
    $csv='C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\csv\\File.csv'; //File location
    $fh= fopen($csv,'r');
    echo '<table style="border:1px solid;">';
    while(list($FirstName,$LastName,$Email)=fgetcsv($fh,1024,','))/* creatubg a table to auto generate based on the amount of rows in*/
{
        echo 
        '<tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid;">',printf("%s",$FirstName),'</td>',
        '<td style="border:1px solid;">',printf("%s",$LastName),'</td>',
        '<td style="border:1px solid;">',printf("%s",$Email),'</td>',
        '</tr>'
        ;
        //  printf("<p>%s, %s, %s </p>",$FirstName,$LastName,$Email);
        
    }
    echo '</table>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't, just chose one and go with it. In php you can concatenate string using the "." so this is an example of your code using concatenation:

```
echo '<tr><td style="border:1px solid;">' . $FirstName . '</td>' .
'<td style="border:1px solid;">' . $LastName . '</td>' .
'<td style="border:1px solid;">' . $Email . '</td>' .
'</tr>';
```